# TOS Galileo Seven decaying orbit problem

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, orbital-mechanics

I've just watched a rerun of **The Galileo Seven** episode from season one of TOS. Am I missing something or did the writers just not understand what an orbit means?

As a desperate measure to escape the planet they are trapped on, the crew launchs the shuttle craft into orbit, but then must continually burn fuel in order to stay in orbit and not burn up in the atmosphere. Now atmosphere drag will cause any close orbit to decay sooner or later, but that's not how I understood the dialog description of their problem. It seemed that the moment they ran out of fuel, they started falling back to the planet. That sounds more like a sub-orbital flight.

Did I misunderstand something, is there an in-universe answer, or is this just sloppy fact checking on the show's part?

Answer (score 7):

You didn't misunderstand anything, nor was this an example of sloppy writing. What you're looking at here is an example of an [extremely low orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit),  presumably less 7km above the planet's surface. At that height, atmospheric drag is extremely high and will cause [orbital decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay) almost immediately without spending fuel on [orbital station-keeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_station-keeping).

Scott explicitly states that the ship only has enough fuel for **a single orbit** (by maintaining a slow burn on their engines) before atmospheric drag and orbital decay cause them to enter the atmosphere proper, with no way of preventing it.

> **SPOCK:** *That is a most illogical attitude. Orbit in one minute, Mister Scott. Fuel status?*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Fifteen pounds psi. **Approximately enough for one orbit, sir.***
>
> **MCCOY:** *After that?*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Tapping our boosters ended our last chance for a soft landing.*
>
> **BOMA:** *You mean a burn-up?*
>
> **SPOCK:** *It is the usual end of **a decaying orbit.***

Comment: Thanks, Valorum. It's 4 AM where I am and I'm going to have to try to wrap my head around this in the (late) morning, when I haven't been up for over twenty hours, but does the definition of orbit include continuously powered flight in order to maintain stability? I looked at the links you included, but my tired brain couldn't glean much from them at this hour. And unfortunately I'm not a physicist and I don't even play one on TV. I'll check in later.

Comment: Fifteen pounds psi? Oh my...

Comment: @Roseunhill - It's called "Stationkeeping". All low earth objects (such as the IIS) need to do it. The lower you are in orbit, the more you need.

Comment: @flq - Depending on how efficient your engines are, that could get you nowhere or to the moon.

Comment: @valorum More comically for me is that the p in psi stands for pound. Also that TOS does not use SI-units :)

Comment: @flq - They seem to use a *mixture* of units; [Miles](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/1.htm), [Kilometers](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/37.htm), [Pounds](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/14.htm), [Kilograms](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/37.htm), [Celsius](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/movie3.html) and [Fahrenheit](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/20.htm).